# Learning GUI programming with GTK+3

Tags: gtk

I am new to GUI programming. I recently installed Gtk+3 version on Linux. But, when I typed following code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static int count = 0;
void button_clicked(GtkWidget *button, gpointer data)
{
printf(“%s pressed %d time(s) \n”, (char *) data, ++count);
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *button;
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
button = gtk_button_new_with_label(“Hello World!”);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
g_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT (button), “clicked”,
GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (button_clicked),
“Button 1”);
gtk_widget_show(button);
gtk_widget_show(window);
gtk_main ();
return 0;
}
```

To run this code I used this command: $ gcc gtk1.c –o gtk1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`

but I had error like this

```
undefined reference to GTK_OBJECT;
undefined reference to GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your code sample is for an old version of GTK+ 2. `GTK_OBJECT` was deprecated in the late GTK+ 2.x versions, and finally removed in GTK+ 3. Same for `GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC`. Both have been moved to the GObject library, where they now stand as `G_OBJECT` and `G_CALLBACK`.

To avoid using outdated code, just get started with the [code samples from the GTK+ 3 documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html).